# Relations between local diffeomorphism and covering map, in a Riemannian manifold scenario.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

I am reading the proof of the Hadamard theorem in Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo[page 150] and there is a technical detail that bothers me:
After he's proven that the exponential map $exp_p$ was a local diffeomorphism, he tries to show it's a covering map. Then he writes, "it is suffice to show that the map has the path lifting property".
I don't get it, why is the path lifting property suffice to make a local diffeomorphism a covering map? Or maybe I misinterpreted him here?

Comment: I think https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122251/local-homeomorphism-curve-lifting-property-gives-a-covering-map should answer your question.

Comment: @QiZhu yes it does thank you